# Forwarding email based on time email was received

Tags: vba, events, outlook

I found a single reference on using VBA to forward emails based on the time of day they were received.

I have a client looking to forward their emails to an after hours service between X and Y times.  I followed a few guides on syntax and operations.

```vb
Private WithEvents objInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objNS As NameSpace
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
' instantiate Items collections for folders we want to monitor
Set objInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
Set objNS = Nothing

Debug.Print "Application_Startup occurred " & Now()

End Sub

Private Sub Application_Quit()
' disassociate global objects declared WithEvents
Set objInboxItems = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim olItems As Items, _
olItem As Object, _
olMailItem As MailItem, _
olAttachmentItem As Attachment, _
bolTimeMatch As Boolean
Set olItems = objInboxItems.Restrict("[Unread] = True")
For Each olItem In olItems
    If olItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set olMailItem = olItem
        'Change the times on the next line to those you want to use
        bolTimeMatch = (Time >= #3:00:00 PM#) And (Time <= #8:30:00 AM#)
        If bolTimeMatch Then
            Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
            Set objItem = olMailItem
            Set objMail = objItem.Forward
            'PUT THE EXTERNAL EMAIL ADDRESS YOU WANT TO USE ON THE NEXT LINE
            objMail.To = "email@email.com"
            objMail.Send
            Set objItem = Nothing
            Set objMail = Nothing
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function IsNothing(Obj)
If TypeName(Obj) = "Nothing" Then
    IsNothing = True
Else
    IsNothing = False
End If
End Function
```

I added a debug print to see that the macro is starting, and I get positive output, but no emails are actually triggering the forward.

This use case is needed because the emails are being forwarded to a transcription service, so a fire and forget solution is desired over manually setting the forward every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the condition will always be False. Break into parts. It is easier to debug.

To process an incoming item apply code to the **Item** in `Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)`.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim bolTimeMatch As Boolean
    Dim objMail As mailItem
    
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        
        bolTimeMatch = (Time >= #3:00:00 PM#)
        
        If bolTimeMatch Then
            
            Set objMail = Item.Forward
            
            objMail.To = "email@email.com"
            objMail.Display    ' objMail.send
                    
        Else
        
            bolTimeMatch = (Time <= #8:30:00 AM#)
            
            If bolTimeMatch Then
            
                Set objMail = Item.Forward
                    
                objMail.To = "email@email.com"
                objMail.Display    ' objMail.send
            End If
                
        End If
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To forward emails you need to use the [Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(method)) method which executes the `Forward` action for an item and returns the resulting copy as a `MailItem` object.

```
Set myItem = mailItem.Forward
myItem.Send()
```

To find items for a specific time slot or date you need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Use the following code for the search criteria:

```
    Dim strFilter As String 
    Dim datStartUTC As Date 
    Dim datEndUTC As Date 

    datStartUTC = oPA.LocalTimeToUTC(Date) 
    datEndUTC = oPA.LocalTimeToUTC(DateAdd("d", 1, Date)) 

    'This filter uses urn:schemas:httpmail namespace 
    strFilter = AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " > '" & datStartUTC & "' AND " _ 
    & AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " < '" & datEndUTC & "'"
```

The helper function which adds quotes:

```
Public Function AddQuotes(ByVal SchemaName As String) As String 
    On Error Resume Next 
    AddQuotes = Chr(34) & SchemaName & Chr(34) 
End Function
```